# Rkhunter warning: file properties have changed

Tags: security, rkhunter

I am testing `rkhunter` on a Ubuntu server 16.04 in Virtualbox.
I received an email alert by `rkhunter` on the 11th of October, inviting me to "Please inspect this machine, because it may be infected".

So I made a scan with `rkhunter` and found the following result:

```
$ sudo rkhunter -c --rwo
Warning: The file properties have changed:
         File: /usr/bin/curl
         Current hash: f025f2f2dca226c921b2b09da78b220656c098652d41c8654dc4853ff3fd1e5a
         Stored hash : cf846b7f3f11fc8af6cf79a2bbad3c8314eec72c1425b49bc9e34cf85a5090bb
         Current inode: 661569    Stored inode: 661888
         Current file modification time: 1507203916 (05-Oct-2017 13:45:16)
         Stored file modification time : 1478126766 (02-Nov-2016 23:46:06)
```

So I decided to check the `curl` package:

```
$ dpkg -S curl
$ echo $?
0
```

As you can see nothing was reported. 
I read [a discussion at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/372271/411830) where it was suggested to check if the hash change was due to an automatic security update. 
Checking `/var/log/apt/history.log` I noticed that there was an unattended-upgrade of `curl` starting in 2017-10-11. 
I wonder: why rkhunter reports 05 October as the file modification date while the upgrade was made the 11 October?

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo rkhunter --update --propupd
```

should be run after any apt upgrades automatically or manualy

Comment: What if you haven't run rkhunter with the option --proupd right after an update? Is there a way to catch up and ensure that a change in file properties is due to an update?

Comment: @Glendalough not other than reading the output of a normal run and guesding from the apt logs.